# ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_QtCore)

Tags: pyqt5

Can anyone tell my why I am getting this error and how to resolve it?

File "seaweedapp.py", line 4, in 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_QtCore)

```
import sys
import logging

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QApplication, QMainWindow, QPlainTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
```

```
Windows 10 Enterprise 65 bit version 1909 (OS build 18363.1977)
PyQt5                         5.15.6
PyQt5-Qt5                     5.15.2
PyQt5-sip                     12.9.0

Path=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Productivity Tools;C:\Users\deck\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts;C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;

PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

Command Prompt Results:

```
(base) C:\Program Files\Schlumberger\PIPESIM_PTK_2021.1>python
Python 3.8.12 (default, Oct 12 2021, 03:01:40) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
```

```
(base) C:\Program Files\Schlumberger\PIPESIM_PTK_2021.1>python "C:\Program Files\Schlumberger\PIPESIM2021.1\PIPESIM Labs\Seaweed ShapeFile Utility\SeaweedApp.py"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Schlumberger\PIPESIM2021.1\PIPESIM Labs\Seaweed ShapeFile Utility\SeaweedApp.py", line 4, in <module>
```

```
import PyQt5 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_QtCore)
```

This program is globally distributed which makes me think that the issue has to be my python installation / system configuration

Comment: A little more context will help: OS, Python and Qt versions, and knowing if you're getting this simply from command line execution, through an IDE (which one?), in a venv, etc. Besides, there's little point in importing a submodule if you then import some (or even all) its names.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Post has been edited to include additional information suggested.